# How to upgrade Swagger design for web api (.net framework 4.6.2)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, swagger

I used old swaggerUI:

[image]


But I want this for web api (.net framework not .net core):


[image]


**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.Net45 -Version 5.2.1
```